# Incompatibilidade entre navegadores

Tags: google-chrome, navegador-de-internet, internet-explorer, genexus

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O nosso sistema esta ficando diferente, dependendo do navegador que é usado (Imagem em anexo). O Genexus possui alguma coisa para evitar isso? ou vou ter que usar uma class para formatar a posição dos números?

Answer (score 0):

O comportamento deveria ser o mesmo para esses browsers. Para controles de tipo Numeric editáveis a posição predeterminada é o alinhamento à direita. 
Seria importante conhecer a versão que você esta testando do GeneXus, e se está utilizando Abstract Layout.

Comment: Estamos usando o GeneXus 15 - Version: 15.0.116888 U6 e estamos usando o Abstract Layout.

Comment: Seria bom enviar um xpz de exemplo via e-mail para a nossa equipe de suporte avaliar essa diferença.